# Cannot produce an eps or pdf chart in Python's Plotyl in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, orca, plotly-python

I am using the python library called `plotly` on `Ubuntu 18.04` and `Python 3.6`.

I need to export the graphs as `.eps` or `.pdf` files.

I use this sample code:

```
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    import decimal
    import plotly
plotly.io.orca.config.executable = '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca'

    x = ['Product A', 'Product B', 'Product C']
    y = [(20/80)*100, (14/80)*100, round(decimal.Decimal(2.256),2)]

    # Use textposition='auto' for direct text
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Bar(
                x=x, y=y,
                text=y,
                textposition='auto',
            )])

    fig.show()
    fig.write_image("fig1.eps")
```

But the figure is shown in a new tab in the browser. It is not written as `eps`. Also, in the command line where I run the python file, I see:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py:84: UserWarning:

Could not import the lzma module. Your installed Python is incomplete. Attempting to use lzma compression will result in a RuntimeError.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample.py", line 15, in <module>
    fig.write_image("fig1.eps")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 2688, in write_image
    return pio.write_image(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1705, in write_image
    fig, format=format, scale=scale, width=width, height=height, validate=validate
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1482, in to_image
    ensure_server()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1344, in ensure_server
    validate_executable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py", line 1139, in validate_executable
    raise ValueError(err_msg)
ValueError: 
The orca executable is required in order to export figures as static images,
but the executable that was found at '/usr/bin/orca'
does not seem to be a valid plotly orca executable. Please refer to the end of
this message for details on what went wrong.

If you haven't installed orca yet, you can do so using conda as follows:

    $ conda install -c plotly plotly-orca

Alternatively, see other installation methods in the orca project README at
https://github.com/plotly/orca.

After installation is complete, no further configuration should be needed.

If you have installed orca, then for some reason plotly.py was unable to
locate it. In this case, set the `plotly.io.orca.config.executable`
property to the full path of your orca executable. For example:

    >>> plotly.io.orca.config.executable = '/path/to/orca'

After updating this executable property, try the export operation again.
If it is successful then you may want to save this configuration so that it
will be applied automatically in future sessions. You can do this as follows:

    >>> plotly.io.orca.config.save()

If you're still having trouble, feel free to ask for help on the forums at
https://community.plot.ly/c/api/python

Here is the error that was returned by the command
    $ /usr/bin/orca --help

[Return code: -11]
```

Note that I installed the `orca` using: `pip3 install orca`. I also added this line in the code:

```
plotly.io.orca.config.executable = '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/orca'
```

But this did not result in producing the `eps` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have Orca properly installed. Unfortunately you [cannot install Orca with pip](https://github.com/plotly/orca/issues/194). Instead follow **Orca's installation method 4:** [standalone binaries](https://github.com/plotly/orca#method-4-standalone-binaries):

1. Download the .AppImage with `wget` from [Orca's release page](https://github.com/plotly/orca/releases). At the time of writing it was: `wget https://github.com/plotly/orca/releases/download/v1.2.1/orca-1.2.1-x86_64.AppImage`
2. Follow the [Linux install instructions](https://github.com/plotly/orca#linux). Make sure you really follow the troubleshooting guides as well (both) - it wasn't easy.